# Postgresql 9.4 JSONB type, Select by date range

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm migrating from Mongodb, and looking how select by range using jsonb type, I have ~2.880.000 records by day and I need query the database by station and date fields, I know how select by time range

```
SELECT * FROM stations WHERE date >= '2014-02-01' AND date <  '2014-03-01 AND station = 'AA01'
```

But I don't know how query the database with JSONB data type.

```
CREATE TABLE stations (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  event JSONB
);

INSERT INTO test(event) VALUES('{"station":"AA01","value":2.31,"date":"2015-01-23 18:02:48.906569865 +0000 UTC"}');
INSERT INTO test(event) VALUES('{"station":"AA02","value":4.1,"date":"2015-01-23 19:02:48.906569865 +0000 UTC"}');
```

Also I'm wondering how get a good performance approach, thanks.

Comment: Why a -1? what is the reason? because I'm migrating from mongodb?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM stations
WHERE to_date(event->>'date', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    BETWEEN '2014-02-01' 
    AND     '2014-03-01'
AND event->>'station' = 'AA01';
```

Comment: how can I do the same thing but with a jsonb 'date' in unix timestamp? I tried WHERE to_timestamp(data->>'Datetime') but doesn't work

Comment: Mmeyer are you sure about date type? Yours seems like not same like `YYYY-MM-DD`.